# Is it possible to extend the DSI connector?

Tags: touchscreen, dsi, connectors

I want to install my Raspberry Pi in my car.

I also want to have a screen visible for the driver while the RPi is somewhere else.

So i want to extend it up to 50cm, is that possible?

Comment: Does the pi have to be somewhere else? It would seem easier to stretch just about any other connection.

Comment: Also do you specifically have a screen that can take DSI input?

Comment: I dont have a screen yet, but i dont have space for the RPi right behind the screen. So for me to consider this option, i must know if its possible to extend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that [these](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=43&t=43737) guys managed to connect a 4m long CSI cable to the camera, so assume that it would be possible to connect a >50cm long DSI cable as well.

Here, you can buy a 30cm DSI cable for your RPi: [AlienSpec CSI/DSI cable](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/AlienSpec-CSI-DSI-Camera-Ribbon-Cable-5cm-10cm-15cm-20cm-30cm-for-Raspberry-Pi-/121051772597?pt=UK_BOI_Electrical_Components_Supplies_ET&var=420115662545&hash=item1c2f3f76b5)

But there is no way to know this for sure at this point since there is'nt any displays available for the DSI connector yet.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can extend it to some length, if 50cm is within that range I don't know, you should try that. But the specification of the bare protocol look promising:

- Serial, serial protocols are more likely to resist longer cables,
- Differential signalling, this type of signalling is also better resistant to longer cable lengths.

**BUT**

- Communication speeds might go into the Giga Hertz, which brings a whole new spectrum of problems with it,
- Control of this output is in the GPU, which is still closed code.

There are already (or soon will be) displays available for this port, with (rumours) touch screen support. The chance of getting some other display to work is at this moment not very high, extending the cable for that special RPi display is a nice test to perform.

If you did tests with this, I hope you'll be so kind to share the results with us.